# service method not returning a promise

Tags: angular

At the moment in my angular 8 application, promise call isnt returning me an exception when an exception occurs. Could somebody tell me how do i make getRepApprovedName to return a promise . If i use return http.get I am getting a syntax error saying brace bracket expected.

Component

```
 private getRepCode = (repCode: string) => {
    this.loading = true;
    const repToSend = fromGenistarCode(repCode);
    if (repToSend === 0) {
      this.splitSaleDetails.repName = '';
      return;
    }
    this.inviteService.getRepApprovedName(repToSend, this.currentUserId).then(rep => {
      if (rep) {
        this.splitSaleDetails.repName = rep.name;
      } else {
        this.splitSaleDetails.repName = '';
      }
      this.fieldDataChanged(new SetSplitSaleDetails(this.splitSaleDetails));
      this.loading = false;
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err.message);
      return this.messageService.add(err.message, 'warning', true);
    });
```

Service

```
public getRepApprovedName = (repId: number, loggedInUserId: number): Promise<any> =>
      this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}representative-name/${repId}/${loggedInUserId}`).toPromise()
```

Proposed solution

```
  this.inviteService.getRepApprovedName(repToSend, this.currentUserId).subscribe(rep => {
      if (rep) {
        this.splitSaleDetails.repName = rep.name;
      } else {
        this.splitSaleDetails.repName = '';
      }
      this.fieldDataChanged(new SetSplitSaleDetails(this.splitSaleDetails));
      this.loading = false;
    },
    error => {
      this.messageService.add(error.message, 'warning', true);
   });






       public getRepApprovedName = (repId: number, loggedInUserId: number): Observable<any> =>
      this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}representative-name/${repId}/${loggedInUserId}`)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Observable` with `HttpClient` and `subscribe` method.

```
this.inviteService.getRepApprovedName(...).subscribe(
  result => {
     // ok
  },
  error => {
     // catch error
  }
);
```

Your `get` method:

```
getRepApprovedName(...): Observable<YourResultType> {
  return this.http.get<YourResultType>(...your url...);
}
```

`HttpClient` get method returns an `Observable` and will automatically catch an error in case of any issue.

Comment: I have updated the post with your proposed solution and dont see any difference

Comment: Also to let you know response is 404 Not Found. Thats because my api sends an 404 response explicity